# 'print to pdf' using cups & python in raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, python-2.x, cups

I'm trying to print-to-pdf an image(e.g. Raspberry-Pi-Logo.png) using cups. I set everything fine and can make my pdf file using command from terminal (its requesting an id of the pdf file and i have found the file in the directory)
.

```
sudo lp Raspberry-Pi-Logo.png
```

But when i'm trying to do that using python, its not working properly. Its requesting an id like before but no output file in the directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
os.chdir("/home/pi/pdf")
os.system("sudo lp Raspberry-Pi-Logo.png")
```